# how to show search result in another page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, window.location

I wanted to show the result of the form into another page. I tried redirecting the result using the `window.href.location` and `localStorage` but it's not redirecting it to another page. I used the `click()` for the `button` to see if it will show on the other page but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The search bar is in `index.html` and after I click the `search` button, I wanted it show the result in another `html` file like `movies.html`

```js
 

 const movieListEl = document.querySelector(".shows");
const moviesForm = document.getElementById("movie__searchbox");

async function main(event) {
    const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
    const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
    const data = await search.json();
    movieListEl.innerHTML = data.Search.map((movie) => movieHTML(movie)).join("");
}

// check when the form is submitted
moviesForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
    const searchBarValue = document.getElementById("searchbar").value; // get input's value everytime the form is submitted
    console.log(searchBarValue);
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent refresh
    // localStorage.setItem("key", searchBarValue);
    // const searchKey = localStorage.getItem("key");
    main(searchBarValue);
});

function movieHTML(details) {
    return `<div class="shows__content">
        <figure class="shows__poster">
            <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
        </figure>
           <div class="poster__description">
            <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
            <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
        `;
}
 

//function click () {
 //    console.log(window.location)
 //    window.location.href = `${window.location.origin}/movies/movies.html`
// }
```

```html
   
  

  <form action="#" id="movie__searchbox" class="nav__search-bar">
    <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="nav__search" placeholder="Search" />
    <button onclick="click()" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
<div class="shows"></div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by another page? lets say that currently you are present in index.html page and this results are fetched in through the api based on the search text and its getting displayed into the div.shows element. Which other page are you taking about

Comment: another HTML file like movies.html to display the result

Comment: If you are doing client side searches aka Javascript, it seems like just altering the layout of the search page will be your best option. Yes, you use localStorage etc.. but learning to modify the DOM of that page seems like your best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your index page don't fetch your api just redirect it to that page where you want to show the result of movie list, just pass single parameter that is your search value.

In your other page where you want to display movie list get the urlParams and then fetch your api and display your movie list as per the given code which I provided below.

**The index page code is**:

```
<form action="#" id="movie__searchbox" class="nav__search-bar">
<input type="text" id="searchbar" class="nav__search" placeholder="Search" />
<button type="submit">Search</button>
```

**Script for this:**

```
 <script>
const moviesForm = document.getElementById("movie__searchbox");
// check when the form is submitted
moviesForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  const searchBarValue = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
  event.preventDefault();
  window.location.href = `movieList.html?value=${searchBarValue}`;
});
```

**The Movie List Page:**

```
<div class="shows"></div>
```

**And The Script for this page (Api fetch for movie as per urlParams):**

```
<script>
    // Retrieve the data from the URL parameters or local storage
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    const value = urlParams.get('value');
    const movieListEl = document.querySelector(".shows");
    async function main(event) {
        const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
        const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
        const data = await search.json();
        movieListEl.innerHTML = data.Search.map((movie) => movieHTML(movie)).join("");
    }
    main(value);
    function movieHTML(details) {
        return `<div class="shows__content">
    <figure class="shows__poster">
        <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
    </figure>
       <div class="poster__description">
        <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
        <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
    </div>
</div>`;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you are doing with `window.href.location` and `localStorage` itself.

I created 2 different files index.html, movies.html

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" id="movie__searchbox" class="nav__search-bar">
        <input type="text" id="searchbar" class="nav__search" placeholder="Search" />
        <button onclick="click()" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <script>
        
        const moviesForm = document.getElementById("movie__searchbox");

        async function main(event) {
            const url = `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=39a36280&s=${encodeURI(event)}`;
            const search = await fetch(`${url}`);
            const data = await search.json();
            localStorage.setItem("movie_list", JSON.stringify(data.Search));
            window.location.href = `${window.location.origin}/movies.html`
        }

        // check when the form is submitted
        moviesForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            const searchBarValue = document.getElementById("searchbar").value; // get input's value everytime the form is submitted
            console.log(searchBarValue);
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent refresh
            // localStorage.setItem("key", searchBarValue);
            // const searchKey = localStorage.getItem("key");
            main(searchBarValue);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

movies.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="shows"></div>
    <script>
        const movie_list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("movie_list"))
        const movieListEl = document.querySelector(".shows");
        movieListEl.innerHTML = movie_list.map((movie) => movieHTML(movie)).join("");

        function movieHTML(details) {
            return `<div class="shows__content">
            <figure class="shows__poster">
            <img src="${details.Poster}" alt="" class="poster">
            </figure>
            <div class="poster__description">
            <h4 class="poster__title">${details.Title}</h4>
            <p class="poster__year">${details.Year}</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            `;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Results

[image: index.html]

[image: movies.html]